# Retrieve CHAIN_ID of the executing chain from a Solidity contract

Tags: solidity, blockchain, genesis, configuration

Is there a way to directly be able to retrieve `CHAIN_ID` information about the executing chain from a smart contract?

I know that for any chain that has [`EIP-155`](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-155.md) implemented, `CHAIN_ID`s are retrievable from the `v` component of a signature but would require the passing of one for extraction.

Since `CHAIN_ID` is information about the chain I suspect that there should be a way to access this. Is there a way for Solidity to directly get this information?

Comment: Alternative: Because you are deploying the contract on a different chain you can give the chain id as a constructor parameter.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As of version `0.5.12`, Solidity includes an assembly function `chainid()` that provides access to the new [`CHAINID` opcode](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-1344.md):

```
function getChainID() external view returns (uint256) {
    uint256 id;
    assembly {
        id := chainid()
    }
    return id;
}
```

To use it, ensure you set the compiler's EVM version to Istanbul with the `--evm-version istanbul` flag.

Related documentation: [Solidity Assembly - v0.5.12](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.12/assembly.html#opcodes)

Comment: very useful answer, thanks! note: for those using ganache: this needs v6.9.1 as eg v6.7.0 doesn't support the CHAINID opcode

Comment: Is there an equivalent function in Vyper?

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg for Vyper - https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/84261/does-vyper-have-an-equivalent-chainid-assembly-function/84264#84264

Answer (score 34):

chainid is available in native solidity 0.8.0. So you can get chain id like block timestamp or block number.

Here is the code.

```
block.chainid;
```

Documentation
https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.0/units-and-global-variables.html

Solidity update PR is here.
https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/pull/10557

Comment: TypeError: "chainid" is not supported by the VM version (v0.8.0)

Comment: FYI "Chain ID is a 256-bit value." - https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1344

Comment: I think the VM version and solidity version is a different thing.
Solidity version v0.8.0 has "block.chainId" but VM implements eip-1344.

Comment: That's seems like the better answer

Comment: CompileError: TypeError: "chainid" is not supported by the VM version. pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

Comment: @Barney Chambers, solidity version and EVM version are two different things, you need to make sure the selected EVM version is at least `Istanbul` for `block.chainid` to compile.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't as of yet, but Istanbul (the upcoming hardfork) includes [eip-1344](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1344), which includes a CHAINID opcode that pushes the chain id to the stack. I assume Solidity will add block.chainId or something similar, or at least add it to Solidity Assembly so that libraries can access it.