# Does Vyper have an equivalent CHAINID assembly function?

Tags: contract-development, vyper

[Since v0.5.12](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/56749/retrieve-chain-id-of-the-executing-chain-from-a-solidity-contract), Solidity provides a `CHAINID` OPCODE in assembly:

```
function getChainID() external view returns (uint256) {
    uint256 id;
    assembly {
        id := chainid()
    }
    return id;
}
```

Is there an equivalent in Vyper?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Vyper [`v0.1.0-beta15`](https://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/v0.1.0-beta.17/release-notes.html#v0-1-0-beta-15) the chain ID is available through the `chain.id` [environment variable](https://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/v0.1.0-beta.17/constants-and-vars.html#block-and-transaction-properties):

Here is a minimal example to verify the behavior:

```py
@public
@constant
def foo() -> uint256:
   return chain.id
```

Note that this is only possible if the compiler is set to target the [Istanbul EVM ruleset](https://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/v0.1.0-beta.17/compiling-a-contract.html#setting-the-target-evm-version) or later.